# What does "it is not given to" mean?

Tags: grammar

> It is not given to all to do this job with celerity.

What is this "it is not given to do" construction?
Where is it in the dictionary?

Answer (score 6):

When people are particularly good at something they are often said to be 'gifted'.

'He is a gifted violinist'. 'She is a gifted volleyball player'. 'Trinity College, Cambridge, which is Isaac Newton's old college, accepts only students who are 'gifted' mathematicians.'

The notion that excellence in ability is some form of gift which has been given from birth runs high in Judeo-Christian society.

Hence the everyday expression 'It is not given to everyone to be able to make a nice cup of tea' is not at all unusual, both in sincerity and, as in my example, when said with irony.

Comment: Can instead of "it's" be some verb or noun?

Comment: My first reaction was to say that "it", used in this way, is an "expletive subject" and doesn't refer to anything. (If you want to know all about expletive subjects - look up "it is raining" on this site). But then people do say things like "John is not given to paying people compliments" - meaning, presumably, that John does not have the gift of paying compliments.

Comment: but if you want to say that someone simply can't do something, let it be "flying", then does this make some point of saying it this way "It's not given to you to fly (as others do)"

Comment: Or "it is not given to all (you) to play football" Is this way possible meaning that you don't have ability of playing football properly

Comment: Where it is specific to an individual it would seem more natural to me to say "You do not appear given to flying..."

Comment: Ok, thank you, but if it not about individual one, as in my last example with word "play" in general

Comment: @Boyep I am sorry but I do not understand your last sentence which is not grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty archaic wording.

*It is not given to all* means that not all people *have the ability*.

Probably meant more like *God has not blessed all men with the ability* to do the job quickly.

Comment: I don't find it in the least archaic. It is an everyday idiom in my reckoning.

Comment: @WS2 Here in the colonies it would be rare, and not readily understood by old hundred names.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany 'Old hundred names' is a reference, as I understand it, to Chinese surnames. I agree that it might not perhaps be understood by people of Buddhist or Taoist origin. That is why, in my answer, I refer to 'Judeo-Christian society'.

Comment: @WS2 Old hundred names is a translation of a Chinese idiom meaning something like Joe Sixpack or Fred Bloggs.  I could imagine saying "It is not given to all to do this job with celerity" in a sports bar (with a sneer) if the bartender was slow in bringing a drink. It might not turn out well.

Comment: Not something I too would dare utter in a pub in Manchester, particularly in reference to the present performance of one of their football teams.

Comment: Huh. I agree with WS2 that _it is not given to all_ is not archaic (formal, yes, but not archaic) and is quite easily understandable to anyone—but I’ve never seen _old hundred names_ before right now, and I had **no** idea what it was supposed to mean until I read WS2’s response, at which point I figured out it’s a direct translation of 老百姓 _lǎo bǎi xìng_.

Comment: @WS2 Good thinking not to utter it where the barman might hear you. Otherwise he just might bring out your next drink with a spear of ***celery*** in it. :)

Answer (score 0):

*It is not given to all to do this job with celerity.*

We can rewrite this as:

*[The ability] to do this job with celerity is not given to all [people][by God or Fate].*